# Display pages in alphabetical order

Tags: pages

I think I am missing something in my `functions.php` because my pages in the admin are displayed randomly. How can you display the pages in admin alphabetically?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your theme using `pre_get_posts` somewhere? This may cause your problem.

Comment: @Nilambar yes, `add_filter('pre_get_posts',...` is there an issue with this?

Comment: Inside that function, you need to check `!is_admin()` to apply query modification only for front end.

Comment: Cheers :-) Have a great day.

Comment: @nilambar Nice job figuring this out. Please post the solution as an answer below (with a bit of description about `pre_get_posts` and `!is_admin()`) so that @claudiu can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter `pre_get_posts` is used for modifying the query from theme or plugin. This hook is called after the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is run.

[Codex documentation of `pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

Although this filter is very handy and useful, we need to be very careful using it. We should very careful about targeting the query. This filter is applied for both front end and back end admin panel. WordPress provides several conditional function which can be used to target the specific page.

- is_main_query()
- is_admin()
- is_home()
- is_post_type_archive()
- and many more

[See here for more conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Example, if you want to target only home page then you can use like this:

```
function my_custom_function( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        //change query parameter here for home page
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_custom_function' );
```